# Where to instantiate controllers in Backbone Marionette?

Tags: oop, controller, marionette

In my application I got controllers in every module, working as mediators.
What would be the better place to instantiate them:

1. In main controller like this:

   ```
   App.MainController = Marionette.Controller.extend({ 
       doSomething: function(){
           var controller = new App.Module1.Controller();
           controller.doSomething();
           ...
       },
       doSomethingElse: function(){
           var controller = new App.Module1.Controller();
           controller.doSomethingElse();
           ...       
       }
   });
   ```
2. or in initialize method of the modules like this:

   ```
   Module1.addInitializer(function(){      
       Module1.controller = new Controller({
           ...
       });
   });
   ```

and call it from main controller:

```
    doSomething: function(){ 
      App.Module1.controller.doSomething();
    },
    doSomethingElse: function(){ 
      App.Module1.controller.doSomethingElse();
    },
```

Is it better to have one global instances of controllers, or create them every time they are needed?
I'm confused.
Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your question is more general than just for controllers.
My preference is that you should only use global instance if there is a need to share across different modules and the data need to be persisted across operations.

If there are no such needs, you should not waste resources to have them around.  Plus the less global instances your have, the more easily to maintain resources in your app.

Hope that help!

Comment: Thank you Ming Chan for explaining the general problem. It was really helpful, but my intention was to find the best solution in particiular problem of Marionette objects used as controllers. I understand that it is the same - it depends on the architecture of the application. If I don't need to keep the state of the module I should instantiate its controller(s) everytime from scratch. And global (in application) objects can be useful only for sharing data.